# Does thread need to get the ownership of the mutex to close the handle of the mutex

Tags: c++, winapi

I saw some example programs about using **mutexes**. I was just wondering whether a thread has to get the ownership of the mutex to close the handle because one of the examples created a mutex as below in main().

```
ghmu_handle = CreateMutex(NULL, false, NULL);
```

And then it

- Created a thread and
- Thread got ownership of the mutex and
- It did some work on critical section and
- Released the mutex by using **ReleaseMutex**().
- Now main() simply called **CloseHandle**(ghmu_handle) with out getting the ownership.

Is it correct way or do we need to get the ownership to close the handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to own the mutex to close the handle.  That would be an unreasonable requirement, since it may not be possible to claim ownership of the mutex, e.g., if another process holds it.

Also note that you cannot release the mutex without the handle.

Comment: You need ownership to **release** the mutex.  You do not need ownership to **close** the mutex handle.